# Delete a column in Excel using Apache poi?

Tags: java, apache-poi

Here is the code I have used. with this I am able to delete the content but not the cell. please  help me with this.

```
File f=new File("C:\\Users\\ALLANSH1\\Desktop\\GL_PLATEAU.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(f);
        XSSFWorkbook workbook=new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        XSSFSheet mysheet=workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int l=mysheet.getLastRowNum();
        java.util.Iterator rowIter =mysheet.iterator();
        while(rowIter.hasNext())
        {
            XSSFRow row=(XSSFRow)rowIter.next();
            XSSFCell cell=row.getCell(5);
            row.removeCell(cell);
        }
        System.out.println(l);
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\ALLANSH1\\Desktop\\GL.xlsx");
        workbook.write(fos);
    }
```

Comment: The solution provided in the above link isn't working. please help me with another solution.

Comment: Hi Shiva, did you find any solution? If yes please do share.

Answer (score -1):

Close your file before you are saving it.

It should be closed after this line

```
System.out.println(l);
fis.close();
```

Comment: that doesn't asnwer the question. It should be a comment